# How to install wxpython for virtualenv

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, python, wxpython

I am on 14.04. The system python version is 2.7.6. I am testing a software meant for python 2.7.9. So I have a virtualenv running python 2.7.9.

Running this `pip install wxpython` doesn't work. So I followed these steps here: [Installing wxPython and wxWidgets on Ubuntu and Debian](http://wiki.wxpython.org/InstallingOnUbuntuOrDebian)

Right now, I can `import wx` using system python (2.7.6). But unable to do so using the virtualenv.

I tried building wxWidgets and wxPython from source using these [instructions](http://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython), but it failed with the following error:

```
In file included from src/helpers.cpp:17:0:
include/wx/wxPython/wxPython_int.h:35:19: fatal error: wx/wx.h: No such file or directory
 #include <wx/wx.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

EDIT:

I tried another option: reinstall virtualenv with `--system-site-packages`

Eg.
`virtualenv venv --system-site-packages`.

This however does not solve the problem as well. In my case, I have installed python 2.7.9 to `~/alternative/bin` ,so running the following command still doesn't import wx into virtualenv:

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages -p ~/alternative/bin/bin/python2.7 my_venv
```